# How create .xltx (Microsoft Excel template file) using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have tried changing the MIME type:

**From:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

**To:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template');
```

But file is corrupted. *Excel* gives error either file is corrupted or wrong format.

Comment: Changeing the header does not change the file content

Comment: Can anyone help creating .xltx file with phpexcel thanks.